# How to load 533 columns of data into snowflake table?

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-pipe

We have a table with 533 columns with a lot of LOB columns that have to be moved to snowflake. Since our source transformation system having an issue to manage 533 columns in one job. We have split ted the columns into 2 jobs. The first job will insert 283 columns and the second job needs to update the remaining column.

We are using one copy command and upsert command respectively for these two jobs.

copy command

```
copy into "ADIUATPERF"."APLHSTRO"."FNMA1004_APPR_DEMO" (283 columns) from @"ADIUATPERF"."APLHSTRO".fnma_talend_poc/jos/outformatted.csv
--file_format = (format_name = '"ADIUATPERF"."APLHSTRO".CSV_DQ_HDR0_NO_ESC_CARET');
FILE_FORMAT = (DATE_FORMAT='dd-mm-yyyy', TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='dd-mm-yyyy',TYPE=CSV, ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE,
SKIP_HEADER=1, field_delimiter ='|', RECORD_DELIMITER = '\\n', FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"',
               NULL_IF = ('')) PATTERN='' on_error = 'CONTINUE',FORCE=true;
```

Upsert command

```
MERGE INTO db.schema._table as target 
 USING
(SELECT t.$1
from @"ADIUATPERF"."APLHSTRO".fnma_talend_poc/jos/fnma1004_appr.csv 
--file_format = (format_name = '"ADIUATPERF"."APLHSTRO".CSV_DQ_HDR0_NO_ESC_CARET');
(FILE_FORMAT =>'CSV', ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD => NONE,
SKIP_HEADER=>1, field_delimiter =>'|', RECORD_DELIMITER => '\\n', FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY => '"',
               NULL_IF => (''))

) source ON target.document_id = source.document_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
--update lst_updated
UPDATE SET <columns>=<values>;
```

I would like to know if we have any other option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you run the `COPY INTO` for both of your split files into temp/transient tables, first.  And then execute a single CTAS statement using the JOIN between those 2 tables on `document_id`.  Don't `MERGE` from a flat file.  You could, optionally, run a `MERGE` on the 2nd temp table into the first table (not temp), if you wished, but I think a straight CTAS from 2 "half" tables might be faster for you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your timely help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your timely help.And also we have around then 50 million records in those tables. What would be your suggestion for efficient way of running. and any calculation to choose the compute power (wearhouse) based on data size.